# Line/Col: 2/10 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JOBS_PKG" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: plsql

I have this package specification and body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE jobs_pkg
IS
    PROCEDURE initialize;
    
    FUNCTION get_minsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER;
    
    FUNCTION get_maxsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER;
    
    PROCEDURE set_minsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2, pmin_salary NUMBER);
    
    PROCEDURE set_maxsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2, pmax_salary NUMBER);
    
END jobs_pkg;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY jobs_pkg
IS

    TYPE jobs_tab_type IS TABLE OF jobs%rowtype INDEX BY jobs.job_id%type;
    jobstab jobs_tab_type;

    PROCEDURE initialize
    IS
    BEGIN
        FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM jobs)
        LOOP
            jobstab(rec.job_id) := rec;
        END LOOP;
    END;
    
    FUNCTION get_minsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
        vmin_salary jobs.min_salary%type;
    BEGIN
        SELECT min_salary
        INTO vmin_salary
        FROM jobs
        WHERE job_id = jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
        
        RETURN vmin_salary;
    END get_minsalary;
    
    FUNCTION get_maxsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS  vmax_salary jobs.max_salary%type;
    BEGIN
        SELECT max_salary
        INTO vmax_salary
        FROM jobs
        WHERE job_id =  jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
        
        RETURN vmax_salary;
    END get_maxsalary;
    
    PROCEDURE set_minsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2, pmin_salary NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE jobs
        SET min_salary = pmin_salary
        WHERE job_id = jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
    END set_minsalary;
    
    PROCEDURE set_maxsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2, pmax_salary NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE jobs
        SET max_salary = pmax_salary
        WHERE job_id = jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
    END set_maxsalary;
    
END jobs_pkg;
```

The problem is that i need to implement a before insert or update statement trigger that uses the call syntax to invoke the jobs_pkg.initialize procedure to ensure that the packate state is current before the DML operations are performed, but i have encountered this problem when i try to compile my trigger: `Line/Col: 2/10 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JOBS_PKG"`

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER init_jobpkg_trg
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON jobs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL jobs_pkg.initialize;
END init_jobpkg_trg;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this? Why do you want to load up the entirety of the jobs table into an array every time you update or insert into the table? It really looks like the min/max salary logic could be implemented in a view, and that way you don't need a trigger at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invoke a procedure from within another pl/sql block (procedure/function/trigger/anonymous block) you don't need the `EXEC` or `CALL` keyword. Just "package.procedure;" will do.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER init_jobpkg_trg
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON jobs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    jobs_pkg.initialize;
END init_jobpkg_trg;
```

Note that you'll most probably run into other issues. When updating the table the trigger is on you risk getting a `MUTATING TABLE` error because you're getting in an infite loop. Because when you update the table on update, that update will fire the trigger ... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`CALL` is not a recognised PL/SQL command. Instead, to call a procedure, you just refer to it by name. That means, essentially, you just need to remove `CALL`, like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER init_jobpkg_trg
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON jobs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  jobs_pkg.initialize;
END init_jobpkg_trg;
/
```

N.B. you will note that I have added a '/' at the end of the PL/SQL - although this character is not required by some (most?) GUIs such as Toad or PL/SQL Developer, it's good practice to always add it after a PL/SQL block, since SQL*Plus requires it, and its absence can cause problems when running scripts. You should add one after your `CREATE OR REPLACE package [body] ...` blocks too.